# Swift 3 - How I Do Page From Bottom To Top In UITableView In A Chat App?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, paging

I have messaging data when I open UITableView Controller. I want to see the last message. How can I go about doing this? Should I reload the table for each message or should I insert the cell for each message?

Comment: Can you add your code to your question showing what you've done so far?

Comment: Insert the cell for each message. ReloadData is a resource heavy and also the UI will always flash for each message

Comment: You mean you want to scroll table view to the bottom on reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We developed a surplus trading software before, it also has a messaging feature. What we did is that when the user chose to refresh the whole message flow, then that is the time the whole table will be refreshed. But when there are new messages arriving from the server. We would only insert new data to the table. If there are updates for a certain message. Then we would just reload that certain row.

Because reloading the whole table will take up a lot of resources, especially when you have a big amount of data. So, don't reload the whole table as long as you don't have to.